# How to add a constraint that choose one tuple from a set?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, tuples, cplex, opl

If I have a tuple like this

```
tuple index{
int i;
int j;
int k;
}
{index}indexs=
{
<1 1 1><1 1 2> <1 2 1> <1 2 3> <2 1 2> <2 1 4>
}
```

How can I add a constraint that if i and j are the same, choose a tuple from it?

Like, forall(i,j) sum(k in **??**) `x[i][j][k]=1`

Which means, choose one tuple from <1 1 1> and<1 1 2>, one tuple from <1 2 1> <1 2 2> <1 2 3> and one tuple from <2 1 2> <2 1 4>?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter within the forall. Assuming `i` comes from `I`, `j` comes from `J` and `k` comes from `K`, you can write

```
forall(i in I)
  forall(j in J : i == j)
    sum(k in K) x[<i,j,k>] >= 1;
```

Or, if `I` and `J` are the same just

```
forall(i in I)
  sum(k in K) x[<i,i,k>] >= 1;
```

Comment: But `K` is not from 1 to k, can you show an example how to filter it? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This looks like the same question as https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f5f3efeb-a983-486c-99ce-800f2e3b8193&ps=25

Comment: Then you have to say what `K` is in your case. If you only post parts of your code then I can only guess.
Note that I am not assuming here that `K` is from a range. It could be a set as well.